# Make a simple href link in Nativescript Ios & Android

Tags: android, ios, hyperlink, nativescript

Good Evening,

I have a simple question, how to create a link in an application made with VueJs & Nativescript for Ios & Android.

I have a online shop and I want user to be able to visit this shop just by clicking a link/button in my app. The click would launch the browser on mobile.

Lets say I have [www.shop.com](http://www.shop.com) I want a link like this : [My Link](http://www.shop.com).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nativescript-stackblitz-templates-g4xxmq?file=app/components/Home.vue) of how you could do it.

The important part is here if you just want to see, not run it.
In short, use a `Label` with class `link` to style it as a link, and use `openUrl` to launch the link in the browser.

```
<template>
  <Page>
    <ActionBar>
      <Label text="Home" class="font-bold text-lg" />
    </ActionBar>

    <GridLayout>
      <Label
        class="text-xl align-middle text-center link"
        :text="linkText"
        @tap="openLink"
      />
    </GridLayout>
  </Page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import { Utils } from '@nativescript/core';

export default Vue.extend({
  computed: {
    linkText() {
      return 'My Link';
    },
  },
  methods: {
    openLink() {
      Utils.openUrl('https://nativescript.org');
    },
  },
});
</script>

<style>
.link {
  color: #0645ad;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```

In case you don't want to rely on the built in Utils.openUrl(), you can call the native API directly, for example like this on iOS:

```
import { Application } from '@nativescript/core';

const app: UIApplication = Application.ios.nativeApp;
const options = NSDictionary.dictionary<string, any>();
const callback = (success) => {
  console.log('openUrl: ', success);
};
app.openURLOptionsCompletionHandler(NSURL.URLWithString('https://nrk.no'), options, callback);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
But isn't "openurl" deprecated especially for IOS ?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Utils.openUrl() is using UIApplication.sharedApplication.openUrl(), and NativeScript has not updated this yet.

Luckily, if you want to call the new method, you can do this by calling the native API directly. I've updated the answer to show how.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Utils.openUrl => seems to work on android & IOS 16.
For Ios 16 the number phone link like = "tel:0000000000" don't work.

I tried your solution specific for IOS but i get this error :
"Cannot find name 'Application'. Did you mean 'UIApplication'?"

Comment: You have to `import { Application } from '@nativescript/core';`. I'm not sure why `openUrl('tel:0000000000')` doesn't work for you, as it works fine for me. You can check Apple's docs on [URL schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899) for more details.

Comment: About the tel: url it seems that you have to write it like this :
tel://000000000